# Scaling canvas unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

In all canvas training videos in unity, when creating a canvas, blue dots appear that you can use to scale the object. I don't have any:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Badh.png)

How do I add them? Maybe my settings are not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings are not different. I believe what you are describing is the `Rect Tool`. You can either select the tool on the top left selection by clicking the icon with 4 vertex points **or** when you have the editor open, click **T** and it will automatically swap to this tool. The points on your UI image will appear and you will be able to scale it using them.

[image: Rect Tool]